# Blit pvrtc texture metal

Tags: metal, metalkit

I'm trying to blit buffer to PVRTC texture. The reason why I'm doing it, because want to keep texture with private storage.

Here is quote from documentation.

> If the texture's pixel format is a compressed format, then sourceSize
>   must be a multiple of the pixel format's block size or be clamped to
>   the edge of the texture if the block extends outside the bounds of a
>   texture. For a compressed format, sourceBytesPerRow is the number of
>   bytes from the start of one row of blocks to the start of the next row
>   of blocks.

Something wrong in my code, because texture looks broken after.

```
MTLBlitOption options = MTLBlitOptionNone;    

if (_pixelFormat == MTLPixelFormatPVRTC_RGB_4BPP || _pixelFormat == MTLPixelFormatPVRTC_RGBA_4BPP) {
    uint32_t blockWidth = 4;
    uint32_t blockHeight = 4;
    uint32_t bitsPerPixel = 4;
    uint32_t blockSize = blockWidth * blockHeight;
    uint32_t widthInBlocks = width / blockWidth;
    uint32_t heightInBlocks = height / blockHeight;

    options = MTLBlitOptionRowLinearPVRTC;

    levelBytesPerRow = widthInBlocks * ((blockSize * bitsPerPixel) / 8);
}

id <MTLBuffer> buffer = [device newBufferWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] options:0];

[blitEncoder copyFromBuffer:buffer 
               sourceOffset:0 
          sourceBytesPerRow:levelBytesPerRow 
        sourceBytesPerImage:[buffer length] 
                 sourceSize:MTLSizeMake(width, height, 1)
                  toTexture:self.textureMetal 
           destinationSlice:0 
           destinationLevel:i 
          destinationOrigin:MTLOriginMake(0, 0, 0) 
                    options:options];
```

Comment: Are you sure your data is correct? Its length is `height * levelBytesPerRow`? Are you sure there's no padding between rows of blocks? If you're filling mipmap levels, how does that figure into the calculation of the size and which data object you're using? Because presumably you'd need different, smaller data objects for each level. Have you run with validation enabled and does it cause errors?

Comment: I think you meant `heightInBlocks * levelBytesPerRow`, yes data sizes valid. replaceRegion: works fine.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry. Well, you can use a temporary shared texture instead of a temporary buffer. Use `replaceRegion:` on the CPU side to populate that temporary texture and then blit from that to the private texture. Another thing that may explain your issue: are you properly synchronizing the buffer such that you don't overwrite it while the blit command is still in flight? (The code looks like it's probably a one-time-use buffer, but hard to say because it's only a fragment.)

Comment: @KenThomases yes, it's one time use. I just realised that it's could be corrupted, because I don't wait until command buffer completed on GPU. So I call `waitUntilCompleted`, and still the same problem. I did in the way you suggest with temporary texture and then blit into mipmap, it works.

Comment: I'm not familiar with metal but am quite familiar with PVRTC and the hardware.  I am surprised to see blits supported with PVRTC as I don't think it was with, say, OpenGL.

Having said that, in hardware, PVRTC1 is usually stored in twiddled/Inverted-Morton order. If it were to be written in raster order, it'd cause some weird effects.